# How expensive is generating a random number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, ruby-2.4

Say you want to generate a random number between 1 and 1 billion:

```
rand(1..1_000_000_000)
```

Will Ruby create an array from that range every time you call this line of code?

Rubocop suggests this approach over `rand(1_000_000_000)+1` but it seems there's potential for pain.

Ruby's docs say this:

```
# When +max+ is a Range, +rand+ returns a random number where
# range.member?(number) == true.
```

Where `+max+` is the argument passed to `rand`, but it doesn't say how it gets the `number` argument. I'm also not sure if calling `.member?` on a range is performant.

Any ideas?

I can use benchmark but still curious about the inner workings here.

Comment: If the documentation mentions `Range` specifically, you can be pretty sure it’s efficient. You can also just try with more memory than you have: `rand(1..2**64)`

Comment: Can you expand? I know they're lazy loaded for enumerating but why else are they efficient? Like, why in this case?

Comment: You asked whether or not an array is created. As the other Ryan said, you can test that easily, by asking for a random number in a range that is so large that allocating an array for it would consume more than your available memory. If the code works, then no array is created, if the code starts thrashing the swap file, or raises an out of memory exception, then the intermediate array is created.

Comment: Calling `member?` on a range is constant, it is just `left <= i && i <= right`. But that is irrelevant, because `member?` is never going to be called anyway. The documentation only says that it will return a number that is inside the range, so that *if you **were** to call `member?`, it **would** return `true`*.

Comment: Since you seem to be satisfied that it’s possible to compute `rand(1_000_000_000) + 1` without creating an array: `rand(a..b)` can just evaluate `rand(b - a + 1) + a`.

Comment: I don't understand how creating an array would help, as you would then need to compute a random index, which is the same problem.

Comment: Definitely don't think it would help, just wasn't sure if it would. Seems like the answer is that it never will and Rubocop's approach is safe. I ran both styles with Benchmark and they're close enough performance-wise that it doesn't make a difference. Thanks for the comments. Happy to accept an answer that sums this stuff up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Ruby will not create an array from that range, unless you explicitly call the `.to_a` method on the `Range` object. In fact, `rand()` doesn't work on arrays - `.sample` is the method to use for returning a random element from an array.

The `Range` class includes `Enumerable` so you get Enumerable's iteration methods without having to convert the range into an array. The lower and upper limits for a Range are `(-Float::INFINITY..Float::INFINITY)`, although that will result in a `Numerical argument out of domain` error if you pass it into `rand`.

As for `.member?`, that method simply calls a C function called `range_cover` that calls another one called `r_cover_p` which checks if a value is between two numbers or strings.

To test the difference in speed between passing a range to `rand` and calling `sample` on an array, you can perform the following test:

```
require 'benchmark'

puts Benchmark.measure { rand(0..10_000_000) }
=> 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000009)

puts Benchmark.measure { (0..10_000_000).to_a.sample }
=> 0.300000   0.030000   0.330000 (  0.347752)
```

As you can see in the first example, passing in a `range` as a parameter to `rand` is extremely rapid.

Contrarily, calling `.to_a.sample` on a range is rather slow. This is due to the array creation process which requires allocating the appropriate data into memory. The `.sample` method should be relatively fast as it simply passes a random and unique index into the array and returns that element.

To check out the code for `range` [have a look here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/50a99a76791bcd09b15353d704226a9cb52fd2b9/range.c).